# Erro aiohttp loops simultâneos (attached to a different loop)

Tags: python-3.x, async

```py
_LOCK_DB_1 = asyncio.Lock()
_DATABASE_1 = 'database.db'


async def cache_actives():
    global _DATABASE_1, _LOCK_DB_1
    while True:
        async with _LOCK_DB_1:
             db = await aiosqlite.connect(_DATABASE_1)
             ...




async def insert_strategy(app):
    global _DATABASE_1, _LOCK_DB_1
    while True:
        try:
            data = await app['STRATEGY'].get()
            async with _LOCK_DB_1:
                data = json.loads(data)
                ....



async def start(app):
   asyncio.create_task(insert_strategy(app))
   asyncio.create_task(cache_actives())

def main():
    app = aiohttp.web.Application()
    app.on_startup.append(start)
    ...
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host=HOST, port=PORT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Basicamente eu quero que quando um dos loops estiver ativo o outro tecnicamente esperaria o outro terminar para poder consultar o banco de dados, porem isso não acontece e me dispara o seguinte erro `Task <Task pending name='Task-12' coro=<insert_strategy() running at server.py:364>> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop` gostaria de saber oque estou fazendo de errado, ja li a documentação do AIOHTTP e lá eles dizem explicitamente que para iniciar uma Task se usa o `on_startup`, mas parece não funcionar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

problema pode ser resolvido removendo `async with _LOCK_DB_1` e quando for abrir uma conexão com o banco de dados passar o parâmetro isolation_level`db = await aiosqlite.connect(_DATABASE_1,isolation_level=None)` Assim existiria vários leitores e apenas um escritor

[Tirado desse artigo](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).